# gcloud dns access problems

Tags: gcloud, terraform

I'm trying to manage all the infrastructure on GCP via Terraform.
I'm completely unable to set up DNS managed zone with service account.
The service account has "owner" role in the project I'm trying to manage. In fact, the project itself was created with that service account.

When I try to add zone via gcloud, I get:

> API [dns.googleapis.com] not enabled on project []. Would 
>   you like to enable and retry?

Of course, this API is enabled, and I'm able to create zones with other account. So any ideas on what role shoud I add to the service account?

---UPDATE---
Tried disabling this api with gcloud services disable dns.googleapis.com and I am perfectly able to do it-both disable and enable Cloud DNS API, then I've tried to create a new zone with gcloud dns managed-zones create --dns-name="somedomain.xyz." --description "Test Domain" testdomain, system would ask me to enable Cloud DNS API, enables it successfully and... tells me it is not enabled next:

> gcloud dns managed-zones create --dns-name="somedomain.xyz."
>   --description="Test Domain" "testdomain" API [dns.googleapis.com] not enabled on project []. Would  you like to enable and retry?  (y/N)?  y
>
> Enabling service dns.googleapis.com on project ... Waiting for async
>   operation operations/tmo-acf.02504b50-c3ec-42de-ad3b-23e39f2bc7a4 to
>   complete... Operation finished successfully. The following command can
>   describe the Operation details:  gcloud service-management operations
>   describe operations/tmo-acf.02504b50-c3ec-42de-ad3b-23e39f2bc7a4 API
>   [dns.googleapis.com] not enabled on project []. Would  you like to
>   enable and retry?  (y/N)?

Comment: I was having a lot of problems with this a day or two ago, starting to sound like some bug on Google's part.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm running into the same issue using Terraform; everything looks like it is set up correctly, TF service account has DNS Admin permissions but getting API not enabled error.